# ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Chrome not persisting AspNet.Consent Cookie over HTTP

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

`ASP.NET Core 3.1` and `Chrome` is ignoring `Consent Cookie`.

When I test with Safari it works, but Chrome is ignoring the cookie over HTTP, in my development environment.

In my production environment this is not happening, and I can see the `".AspNet.Consent"` being set using Chrome developer tools.

Here is the code, it is failing for the "Dev" environment; In the prod environment the application runs behind an `AWS ELB`, which does the `HTTPS`, and forwards the requests as `HTTP`.

The strange bit is my `Auth Cookies` are persisting in `Chrome` for the "Dev" environment over `HTTP`, using the same `GetCookieOptions` function. Initially this was also failing but after setting the `IsEssential` to true I was able to set a Auth cookies.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        });



    private CookieOptions GetCookieOptions() {
        var options = new CookieOptions { 
            HttpOnly = true, // not accessible via Javascript
            Secure = environment.EnvironmentName.Contains("Dev") ? false : true, // only over https
            SameSite = environment.EnvironmentName.Contains("Dev") ? SameSiteMode.None : SameSiteMode.Strict,  // not sent to different url's
            IsEssential = true // required for Chrome
        };
        return options;
    }

    private void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options = GetCookieOptions();
        if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
        {
            var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
            if (DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
            {
                options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the `document.cookie` value after it has been saved, do not assume
that setting a value to the `document.cookie` object will be accepted by the browser.

e.g.

After this line of JavaScript code executed, the document cookie that was being set
was being ignored.

```
document.cookie = button.dataset.cookieString;
```

the cookieString value:

```
".AspNet.Consent=yes; expires=Fri, 18 Jun 2021 00:20:57 GMT; path=/; samesite=none"
```

The problem was within `Chrome` itself...

In Chrome go to this url: `chrome://settings/content/siteDetails`

Search for the host and clear the cookies for the site, e.g. `localhost`